# java bean type arraylist get is undefined for type object

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I have a jsp that I am defining a bean on and trying to get a List of objects to the page

```
<bean:define id="listOfNamesAndAges" name="namesAndAges" property="availableNamesAndAges"/>
<%
   System.out.println(listOfNamesAndAges.getClass()) // prints out java.util.ArrayList

%>
```

I can print out the object such as `System.out.println("data: " + listOfNamesAndAges);` and can see that it is populated like `[name:Daveage:22]`

however I am unable to call methods such as `size()`,`get(int)` `listOfNamesAndAges.get(0)" as it brings back`the method get(int) is undefined for the type Object

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/j2ee101302/working_with_struts/f1_struts_tags/f1_editorbeandefine.html) the documentation for `<bean:define>` tag, this is what it says about `type`:

> type:
>
> Specifies the fully qualified class name of the value to be exposed as the id attribute.

If the type is `ArrayList` in your case, can you try adding `type="java.util.ArrayList"` attribute in `<bean:define>` tag.